# Content is jumping off the algorithm box

Tags: formatting, align, algorithms

My algorithm content is not written within the boundary of the algorithm box. I am using IEEEtrans.

[image]

```
\begin{algorithm}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

\textbf{Data}: \\


\For{$\omega = 1,2, \cdots, N$}{
Principles $Z_n=(z_{1},\cdots , z_{n})$:\[\]
\vspace{-1.25cm}\hspace{0.25cm} $Z_n=(z_{1},\cdots, z_{n}) = (X_n-1_n) $

}
\Output{Outlier score}
\caption{Alg 1.}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Please post a *complete* code we can copy/paste and compile, not a code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I am really not at all familiar with both this documentclass nor the package required, but it seems to me (after trial-and-error) that you cause this yourself by adding the `\vspace{}` and `\hspace{}`.

If you remove them and the additional `\[\]` enviroment (why was this there in the first place?) it seems to work.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    
    \textbf{Data}: \\
    \For{$\omega = 1,2, \cdots, N$}{
        Principles $Z_n=(z_{1},\cdots , z_{n})$:
        $Z_n=(z_{1},\cdots, z_{n}) = (X_n-1_n) $
    }
    \Output{Outlier score}
    \caption{Alg 1.}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

and this is what it looks like for me:

[image]

**EDIT:**
You can simply add more equations in new lines, they do the receive a number with the `linesnumbered` option:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithm}
        \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
        \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
        
        \textbf{Data}: \\
        \For{$\omega = 1,2, \cdots, N$}{
            Principles $Z_n=(z_{1},\cdots , z_{n})$:
            $Z_n=(z_{1},\cdots, z_{n}) = (X_n-1_n) $
            $Z_n=(z_{1},\cdots, z_{n}) = (X_n-1_n) $
            $Z_n=(z_{1},\cdots, z_{n}) = (X_n-1_n) $
            $Z_n=(z_{1},\cdots, z_{n}) = (X_n-1_n) $
            $Z_n=(z_{1},\cdots, z_{n}) = (X_n-1_n) $
        }
        \Output{Outlier score}
        \caption{Alg 1.}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I added `\[\]` so that I jump to the next line without addign a number inside algorithm body as the equation is within "Principles Z_n". If you have alternative way, please let me know?

Comment: Suppose I want to add 10 equations inside Principles Z_n body without number them, how I can do that as this is my issue.

Comment: To answer that properly, I would need to know how you create the numbers in the first place. Could you maybe add the relevant parts of your preamble to your question with an edit?

Comment: @Abraheem: I added something to my answer. Does this help you?